# Custom class decorator TypeORM (decorator in decorator)

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typescript-decorator, nestjs-typeorm

I'm trying to implement a custom class decorator that will implement multiple fields:

```js
export function UserEntity<T extends { new(...args: any[]): any }>(): ((target: T) => T) {
    return (entity: T) => {
        class Temp extends entity {
            @ManyToOne(...)
            @Column({
                name: 'created_user_id',
                type: 'int4',
            })
            createdUserId?: number | null;

            @ManyToOne(...)
            @Column({
                name: 'modified_user_id',
                type: 'int4',
            })
            modifiedUserId?: number | null;
        }

        return Temp;
    }
}
```

However this causes the TypeORM error: *`No metadata for "Temp" was found.`*, which makes sense because no table or entity for `Temp` exists, however when I try to use an anonymous class, I will not let me use decorators:

```js
    return (entity: T) => {
        return class extends entity {
            @ManyToOne(...)
            @Column({
                name: 'created_user_id',
                type: 'int4',
            })
            createdUserId?: number | null;

            @ManyToOne(...)
            @Column({
                name: 'modified_user_id',
                type: 'int4',
            })
            modifiedUserId?: number | null;
        }
   }
```

Then it complains: *`Decorators are not valid here.ts(1206)`*.

I've also tried something like this, no error, but doesn't seem to do anything:

```js
    applyDecorators(Column({
        name: 'created_user_id',
        type: 'int4',
    }))(entity, 'createdUserId');

    applyDecorators(Column({
        name: 'created_user_id',
        type: 'int4',
    }))(entity, 'updatedUserId');

    applyDecorators(Expose())(entity, 'createdUserId');
    applyDecorators(Expose())(entity, 'updatedUserId');
```

So the real question, how can I use/create a custom decorator, with also applying existing decorators?